# How to get the response and logs of a Jenkins test without using the interface, from command line using curl?

Tags: rest, jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I am using curl command to build a job in Jenkins:

```
curl --user "admin:passwd" -X POST http://localhost:8080/job/jobname/build
```

How can I check if the test was successful or failed and how to get the logs of that build from command line only, preferably using curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have BlueOcean plugin installed, you can query its API. This usually returns JSON output that you might need to question further.

First, you need to find the build number triggered by your `curl` command. Then, you need to wait until your build is over. Then, you can question the result.

A good start is:

```
"curl -s ${your_jenkins}/blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/${jobname}/runs/${buildbumber}/nodes/?limit=10000"
```